# How to store a symmetric key safely ? Can I use pkcs12 to store symmetric key?

Tags: c++, c

How to store a symmetric key safely? Can I use pkcs12 to store this symmetric key?

Comment: Please tell us what exactly you want to do and what these keys you are talking about are and what they are for.

Comment: @RIJIK this symmetric key will be used for AES encryption for the  cleartext. This AES cipher will have IV as well. I need to find a way to store this symmetric key in window, Unix and mainframe env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer: It is impossible. As soon as "you" store the key, it is unsafe as your program is just a usual program running on a computer.

Some better ways (depending on your use-case)
- use hardware tokens and their associated drivers / APIs 
- use the operating system's crypto APIs and credential stores 
- encrypt the keyfile with another layer of security, e.g., a password

The second approach is the most widely used as far as all involved operating systems support this.